# React useContext always return default values

Tags: reactjs

React useContext always return default values rather than updated values. Could anyone please tell me how to fix? Maybe because the following consumer is not the child of the following provider?

I'm making a sign in function. The provider is the most outside element App describing routes. The consumer is inside routes. When I use `useContext` in the consumer, the returned values are always default value instead of the values passed to the provider. I need to use the values passed to the provider.

Provider

```
// App.tsx

import React, { useState, useEffect, createContext } from "react";
import { UserIndexPage } from "components/pages/UserIndexPage";
import { UserLoginPage } from "components/pages/UserLoginPage";
import { Layout } from "components/pages/Layout";
import { Routes, Route, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { User } from "interfaces/auth";

export const AuthContext = createContext({
  loading: false,
  setLoading: () => {},
  isSignedIn: false,
  setIsSignedIn: () => {},
  currentUser: undefined,
  setCurrentUser: () => {},
} as {
  loading: boolean;
  setLoading: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
  isSignedIn: boolean;
  setIsSignedIn: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
  currentUser: User | undefined;
  setCurrentUser: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<User | undefined>>;
});

export const App = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [isSignedIn, setIsSignedIn] = useState(false);
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState<User | undefined>(undefined);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        loading,
        setLoading,
        isSignedIn,
        setIsSignedIn,
        currentUser,
        setCurrentUser,
      }}
    >
      <Layout>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={UserIndexPage()} />
          <Route path="/login" element={UserLoginPage()} />
        </Routes>
      </Layout>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Consumer

```
import { useState, useContext } from "react";
import "../../styles/pages/UserIndexPage.css";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";
import { signIn } from "lib/auth/methods";
import { AuthContext } from "App";

export const UserLoginPage = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const { setIsSignedIn, setCurrentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);

  const handleSubmit = async (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const res = await signIn({
        email: email,
        password: password,
      });

      if (res.status === 200) {
        Cookies.set("_access_token", res.headers["access-token"] as string);
        Cookies.set("_client", res.headers["client"] as string);
        Cookies.set("_uid", res.headers["uid"] as string);

        setIsSignedIn(true); // the function is the default value () => {}
        setCurrentUser(res.data.data);

        console.log("Signed in successfully!");

        window.location.href = "/";
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>ログイン</h2>
      <form>
        <div className="field">
          <label htmlFor="user_email">メールアドレス</label>
          <br />
          <input
            type="email"
            name="user[email]"
            id="user_email"
            onChange={(event) => setEmail(event.target.value)}
          />
        </div>

        <div className="field">
          <label htmlFor="user_password">Password</label>
          <br />
          <input
            type="password"
            name="user[password]"
            id="user_password"
            onChange={(event) => setPassword(event.target.value)}
          />
        </div>

        <div className="actions">
          <input type="submit" value="ログイン" onClick={handleSubmit} />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
element={UserIndexPage()}
```

You are calling `UserIndexPage` as a function, not creating an element from it. This effectively means that all the stuff you're expecting to be done when `UserIndexPage` gets rendered is instead being done right now, during the rendering of `App`. So the call to `useContext(AuthContext)` happens while rendering `App`, and there is no component higher up the tree from `App` that provides that value so the default is used instead.

You need to do your routes as JSX elements, as in:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<UserIndexPage />} />
  <Route path="/login" element={<UserLoginPage />} />
</Routes>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works and your description is perfect.